# Subscribe AWS SNS to HTTP endpoint without confirmation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, http, amazon-sns

I need to subscribe an AWS SNS topic to a HTTP endpoint that I do not control, but I am blocked by the anti-abuse measure in SNS that requires the subscribed endpoint to confirm the subscription. This would require modifying the web service.

Given that I don't have the ability to modify the web service, that is probably the end of this discussion. I will need to find another solution. *But, I would like to explain my scenario in case there is a workaround:*

The messages we are sending are logs.

It works like this:

1. log_source -> sns_topic
2. sns_topic -> **log_endpoint***
3. **log_endpoint*** -> log_data_store

*** means it is not controlled by us**

AWS SNS is such a wonderful solution to our problem, it is a shame that we cannot leverage it because of this anti-abuse measure.

I believe we are stuck because we have no control with how AWS will form the magic confirmation URL, nor how the log_endpoint will process it.

If there is no workaround, perhaps there is an analogous AWS service that I could leverage?

Comment: Is it ok to have a middle layer (e.g. Lambda). have the lambda subscribe to your SNS and call the http endpoint from your lambda

Comment: That's a workaround. I don't know how to create a subscription without confirmation as well. I'm really interested if it's possible.